# I am currently using DRF token based authentication where i want to give a role to the user of either a mentor or the student, how to achieve that?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

serializers.py for authentication

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework_jwt.settings import api_settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username',)


class UserSerializerWithToken(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    token = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    def get_token(self, obj):
        jwt_payload_handler = api_settings.JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER
        jwt_encode_handler = api_settings.JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER

        payload = jwt_payload_handler(obj)
        token = jwt_encode_handler(payload)
        return token

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
        instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        if password is not None:
            instance.set_password(password)
        instance.save()
        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('token', 'username', 'password')
```

views.py for authentication

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework_jwt.settings import api_settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username',)


class UserSerializerWithToken(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    token = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    def get_token(self, obj):
        jwt_payload_handler = api_settings.JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER
        jwt_encode_handler = api_settings.JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER

        payload = jwt_payload_handler(obj)
        token = jwt_encode_handler(payload)
        return token

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
        instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        if password is not None:
            instance.set_password(password)
        instance.save()
        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('token', 'username', 'password')
```

models.py

```
class NormalUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, max_length=30)
    standard = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    email = models.EmailField()
    mobile_number = models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'User_details'

     
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

class Mentor(models.Model):
    name = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, max_length=30)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
    details = models.TextField()
    ratings = models.FloatField(default=0)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Mentors'

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

These are the two models to which i want to give a role of either a mentor or a student which can be accessible while creation of API's  , i have to tried to use other solutions that are available but all of them are giving some errors, so need help

Answer (score 1):

For this case, I'd suggest extending `AbstractUser` and creating your own customer user with a `user_type` field that indicates if it's a student or mentor.

something like

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=(("MN", "Mentor"), ("NM", "NormalUser"))
```

and then depending on the choice, you create a Mentor or NormalUser model and link it to this.

check the docs to make sure you have it properly set up.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project

Comment: How to add these choices to corresponsing normal user and mentor models as i have mentioned User model as a OnetoOne field to them

Comment: like i am doing                                                                                                                   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, max_length=30)           how to add choice here to meke it a normal user or  a mentor

Comment: you keep that as is, the user_type field is just an indicator for you to know if this user is a normal user or a mentor so you know which OneToOne field to look for (or create when creating a new user)